# MySQL - Select records in a table where none of the associated records in another table equal a certain value

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Sorry if this duplicates someone else's question, but I've been working on this for a long time and haven't found a solution.

I have two tables, `todo_list` (which contains a list of TODO lists) and `task` (which contains a list of TASKS, each of which is associated with one of the TODO lists).

Here's the relevant structure:

**todo_list**

- id

**task**

- id
- todo_list_id (same as *id* in **todo_list**)
- deleted (is 0 or 1)

Multiple tasks are assigned to each TODO list.  I want to be able to select the TODO lists for which all associated tasks are deleted.  How can I do this?

Comment: Do you want "all the lists where all their tasks are deleted" or "all the lists with no undeleted tasks" (the second includes lists with no tasks)?

Comment: Is that second one supposed to be "all the lists with no *deleted* tasks"?  Because "all tasks deleted" and "no undeleted tasks" sound like the same thing to me...

Comment: My point (poorly-expressed) was that you could draw a distinction between a list with no tasks whatsoever (and therefore no deleted tasks) and one with some tasks, all of which are deleted.

Comment: Ohhh, okay.  Well, I'm not sure there will be any TODO lists with no tasks at all.  When the TODO list is created, at least one task must be created with it.  My boss might decide he wants to allow creation of empty TODO lists, but I'm not sure it would make sense.  Anyway, to answer your question, I would want to select any TODO list that had either all deleted tasks or none at all.  The purpose is to know the TODO list can be safely deleted itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do a left join with the join condition specifying only non-deleted tasks. Then, the unjoined rows would be those that have no tasks where `deleted = 0`.

```
SELECT todo_list.* FROM todo_list
LEFT JOIN task ON todo_list.id = task.todo_list_id && task.deleted = 0
WHERE task.todo_list_id IS NULL
```

Comment: Hurray!  It looks like this one does exactly what I need.  I actually tried a query very similar to this but without the `WHERE task.todo_list_id IS NULL` part.  I was so close.  Also I used a different kind of `JOIN`.  I'm going to research MySQL query JOINs so I can understand them better.  Thank you for this solution!

Answer (score 2):

I think the best approach for these types of queries is aggregation:

```
select todo_list_id
from task t
group by todo_list_id
having sum(deleted) = count(*)
```

Or, an alternative `having` clause is:

```
having max(case when deleted = 0 then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

If you are trying to get lists where all tasks are either deleted or undeleted, the following `having` clause works:

```
having min(deleted) <> max(deleted)
```

Comment: These to return any result.  I have one todo list for which all tasks are deleted and a bunch with no tasks deleted so either way I should get something returned.

Comment: This is much better without the derived table.I'm going to withdraw mine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
select distinct tl.id, tName from todo_list tl, task t where 
tl.id=t.todo_list_id and
tl.id not in (select todo_list_id from task where deleted =1);
```

Note : Assuming that deleted records will have value 0 if it is 1 change the value to 0 in the query

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/01b27/9

Hope this helps